# Angular Communicating with backend services using HTTP with Angular 14 and ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, post, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to do a simple post request (register user) from my Angular 14 frontend to an ASP.NET Core Web API. When I use swagger, I am able to get the results I need when an user is added, however when I attempt to do the post request from my Angular app, I get an "undefined" error and I am not exactly sure where I am getting this mixed up or what I missed. I have made sure that the
`HttpClientModule` is imported in the `app.module.ts`

Sign form with `"submit" (click) ="onSignUp()`:

```
<form [formGroup]="signUpForm">
    <div class ="form-group pt-3">
        <span class ="fa fa user p-2"></span>
        <input formControlName="firstName" type="text"  placeholder="FirstName" >
    </div>

    <div class ="form-group pt-3">
        <span class ="fa fa user p-2"></span>
        <input formControlName="lastName" type="text"  placeholder="Last Name" >
    </div>
      
    <div class ="form-group pt-3">
        <span class ="fa fa user p-2"></span>
        <input formControlName="email" type="text"  placeholder="Email" >
    </div>

    <div class ="form-group pt-3">
        <div class="input-field" [class.error] ="signUpForm.controls['userName'].dirty && signUpForm.hasError('required','UserName')">
            <span class ="fa fa user p-2"></span>
            <input formControlName ="userName" type="text"  placeholder="Username" >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class ="form-group pt-3">
        <span class ="fa fa lock p-2"></span>
        <input formControlName="password" [type] ="type"  placeholder="Password">
        <span (click) ="hideShowPass()" class ="fa {{eyeIcon}}"></span>
    </div>
                    
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mt-4 w-100" type="submit" (click) ="onSignUp()">Sign up </button>

    <div class ="text-center pt-4 text-muted">Already have an account?
        <a id="forget" routerLink ="/login">Login</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

`signup.component.ts`:

```
 export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  type: string = "password";
  isText: boolean = false; 
  eyeIcon: string = " fa-eye-slash"; 
  signUpForm! : FormGroup; 
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private auth: AuthService, private router: Router){}
  
      onSignUp(){
          if(this.signUpForm.valid){
            //perform logic for signup
            this.auth.SignUp(this.signUpForm.value)
            .subscribe({
              next:(res =>{
                    alert("entry")
                    this.signUpForm.reset()
                    //this.router.navigate(['login'])
              }), error:(err=>{
                alert(err?.error.message)
              })
            
            })
            console.log(this.signUpForm.value)
          }
          else
          {
           this.validateAllFormFields(this.signUpForm)
           ValidateForm.validateAllFormFields(this.signUpForm)
           //logic for throwing error
          }
  }
```

`auth.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http"
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
//private baseUrl:string = "http://localhost:7200/Registration"; 
private baseUrl:string = "https://localhost:7200/api/Accounts/";
  constructor(private http :HttpClient) { }

SignUp(userForRegistration:any){

  return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}register`,userForRegistration)
 // return this.http.post<any>('${this.baseUrl}authenticate',loginObj)
}

Login(loginObj:any){
  return this.http.post<any>('${this.baseUrl}authenticate',loginObj)
}
}
```

Accounts controller

```
namespace AngularAuthAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class AccountsController : ControllerBase
    {   
        private readonly UserManager<UserInformation> _userManager;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        
        public AccountsController(UserManager<UserInformation> userManager)//, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            //_mapper = mapper;
        }

        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterUser([FromBody] UserInformation userForRegistration)
        {   
            // Check if user exists
            var userExist = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userForRegistration.Email);

            if (userExist!= null)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden,
                    new Response { Status = "Error", Message = "User already exists!" });
            }

            // Add the user to the database 
            var userInfo = new UserInformation
            {
                Name = userForRegistration.Name,
                Surname = userForRegistration.Surname,
                UserName = userForRegistration.UserName,
                Email = userForRegistration.Email,
                ContactDetails = userForRegistration.ContactDetails, 
                NumberOfCandidates = 100,
                CenterType = 1,
                VsoftApproved =true,
                TermsAndConditions = true,
                CenterID = 2
            };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userInfo, userForRegistration.Password);   

            if (userForRegistration == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest();

           // var user = _mapper.Map<UserInformation>(userForRegistration);
         
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                var errors = result.Errors.Select(e => e.Description);

                return BadRequest(new RegistrationResponseDto { Errors = errors });
            }

            return StatusCode(201);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check console.log. Probably a CORS error.